# comparing image in cocos2d-x

Tags: html, cocos2d-x

I'm making a game with cocos2d-x HTML5.
On one layer there are two images which is almost same but have several different area and when I click one of them, if the clicked area of two images has a different pixel, I want to add a sticker to the same location to both images.

I want to ask that how can i compare the image pixel on cocos2d-x HTML5?
and how do I make the click event to place the sticker?

Answer (score 0):

Probably CCImage class will help you.

What I suggest is, as you already have 2 images, and you have know the different area,
you can create a plist Dictionary recording the area position and size.

In your game scene, you can add transparent touchable Sprite created from your config list file, and set a color to it when it is touched.